# Whitespaces below div rows

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to create a simple 10x10 grid with JavaScript. But the output keeps showing a white space under the divs.

First created div rows and then added cell inside each row. I used `display: inline-block` to align the divs. But don't understand why there's white space below each row.

```js
function grid() {

  let gridCount = 10;

  const container = document.querySelector('.container');

  for (let row = 0; row <= gridCount; row++) {

    const gridRow = document.createElement('div');

    for (let cell = 0; cell <= gridCount; cell++) {

      const div = document.createElement('div');

      div.style.display = 'inline-block';
      div.style.height = '0';
      div.style.width = '5%';
      div.style.paddingBottom = '5%';
      div.style.border = ('1px solid black');
      div.style.backgroundColor = ('lightpink');

      gridRow.appendChild(div);
    }

    container.appendChild(gridRow);
  }

}

grid();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

section.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Grid</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <section class="container">

  </section>

  <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The row-div is a block element with no text, but with a `line-height`, so the height will be some counter-intuitive value. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height):

> On block-level elements, it specifies the minimum height of line boxes within the element.

It can be fixed by:

- a) inserting inline content, e.g. `div.innerText = 'a'` (if you plan to have actual text there)
- b) explicitly setting `gridRow.style.lineHeight = 0;`

```js
function grid() {
  let gridCount = 10;
  const container = document.querySelector('.container');
  for (let row = 0; row <= gridCount; row++) {
    const gridRow = document.createElement('div');
    
    gridRow.style.lineHeight = 0;
    
    for (let cell = 0; cell <= gridCount; cell++) {
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      div.style.display = 'inline-block';
      div.style.height = '0';
      div.style.width = '5%';
      div.style.paddingBottom = '5%';
      div.style.border = ('1px solid black');
      div.style.backgroundColor = ('lightpink');
      gridRow.appendChild(div);
    }
    container.appendChild(gridRow);
  }
}
grid();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
section.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Grid</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <section class="container">
  </section>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

- c) converting to [display: grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) (or [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) if the columns are supposed to be independent in each row)

Answer (score 0):

it is strange and I don't know where is the whitespace comes from but you can fix it if you set the row display to flex

```js
    gridRow.style.display = 'flex';
```